# Cannot load settings from file editor.xml

Tags: android-studio

I manually imported my project from Eclipse into Android Studio. Went well, except suddenly it started doing weird things. Trying to open xml files will result wrong java files being opened or half edited java files. Or opening java files will result in xml files being opened. Files are wrongly named (multiple TextView classes???). Or duplicate classes instead of correct file names. I have tried cleaning solution. How to fix it? It started happening after I copied and added an activity manually.

[image]

[image]

This is the message I get when I start it:

[image]

Cannot load settings from file ...

AndroidStudio1.5\config\options\ui.lnf.xml. Error on line 5.

AndroidStudio1.5\config\options\editor.xml. Error on line 7.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but It doesn't seem clear when you say *suddenly it started doing weird things*

Comment: I think it's clear enough since I explained the symptoms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a File | Invalidate Cache / Restart solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

on a windows 7,
File > Invalidate Caches/Restart did the trick for me

Android Studio 2.3.3

[image: Cannot load settings from file ...solved]